# Give included twig component unique ID

Tags: templating

When I include specific Twig template component multiple times, how can I give it a unique ID (or class)?

Components are not inside `for` loop, so I cannot use `loop.index`. I also don't wont to pass unique variable myself when I include it. And using `random` Twig function doesn't ensure that the result is unique.

Let's also assume that each component doesn't have unique Craft element assigned to it, like entry - in such case, I could just use this entry ID.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific with what sort of data you are working with? Personally this is not something I have ever needed to do whilst working with Craft and Twig. That isn't to say that your use case isn't valid, but I can't quite picture what you need this for.

Comment: @JamieWadeI can't give you anything specific, because there isn't any use case I'm thinking of now. When I create "page builder" using matrix field, templates of specific blocks of matrix can have JS included in them. And I want this JS to work only on specific instance of block, no other blocks. So naturally, I use matrix element block ID to give unique HTML attribute to div and then I run javascript using that unique attribute. I was just wondering how to do such a thing where there is no unique ID available that comes from Craft elements.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for explaining! Looks like Robin has solved this for you anyway :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a unique ID function in PHP and pass it to Twig

```twig
{% set uniqueId = uniqueId() %}
```

And your PHP part

```PHP
class Extension extends \Twig_Extension implements \Twig_Extension_GlobalsInterface
{
    public $uniqueIds;

    public function getFunctions(): array
    {
        return [
             new Twig_SimpleFunction('uniqueId', [$this, 'getUniqueId'])
        ];
    }

    /**
     * getUniqueId
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUniqueId(): string 
    {
        // generate a random string
        $id = StringHelper::randomString('12');

        // check if it's already set
        while (\in_array($id, $this->uniqueIds, true)){
            // if so, use another one
            $id = StringHelper::randomString('12');
        }
        // set it as "used"
        $this->uniqueIds[] = $id;

        return $id;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of some Twig only Solution, but this is also useful - thanks!

Comment: where would this php file sit in Craft's folder structure?

Comment: Where ever you like. Craft doesn't make any assumptions about your custom folder structure. You need to include your files to your composer and register your Twig extension via module/plugin but you can place them where you like. There is no strict path as in Craft 2.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in Craft CMS, but an available native solution in Twig is `random()`

```
{{ random() }} {# example output: 15386094 (works as the native PHP mt_rand function) #}
```

More info in the official [twig documentation page](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/random.html).

Comment: Wouldnt this potentially output same number multiple times? Miniscule chance, but possible.

Comment: It could be, since it looks is not cryptographically safe